# TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined error in reactjs login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to create a login page and I'm getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as I'm fairly new. I wanted to create protected routes for my dashboard page so I tried to use react auth hook context for creating the protected routes. Am I getting this error cause there are no token stored in backend or does it set the token in frontend itself? I have no idea of token or authorization so I'm really confused as to where to look for it. Should I ask the backend guy to store a token variable in the backend or I can do something myself in the frontend? My pages looks like this:

Login.js

```
import React, { Component, useContext, useState } from "react";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "./auth";
import "./App.css";

const Login = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { setToken } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const performLogin = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var body = {
      password: password,
      email: email
    };
    console.log(body);
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const url = "/api/authenticate";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const text = await response.text();
      console.log(response.token);
      if (text === "redirect") {
        setToken(response.data.token);
        setLoggedIn(true);
      } else if (text === "verifyemail") {
        this.props.history.push(`/verifyOtp/${this.state.email}`);
      } else {
        console.log("login failed");
        window.alert("login failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    this.props.history.push(`/dashboard`);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="loginForm">
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <TextField
            hintText="Enter your Email"
            floatingLabelText="Email"
            onChange={(event, newValue) => setEmail(newValue)}
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            type="password"
            hintText="Enter your password"
            floatingLabelText="password"
            onChange={(event, newValue) => setPassword(newValue)}
          />
          <br />
          <RaisedButton
            label="Submit"
            primary={true}
            style={style}
            onClick={performLogin}
          />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const style = {
  margin: 15
};
export default Login;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./login";
import Dashboard from "./dashboard";
import { AuthProvider } from "./auth";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <div className="container">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navheader">
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to={"/Login"} className="nav-link">
                      Login
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <br />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

dashboard.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "./auth";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { setToken } = useContext(AuthContext);

  function logOut() {
    setToken();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>hello</div>
      <button onClick={logOut}>Logout</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Dashboard);
```

edit: auth.js

```
import React, { createContext,  useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

let reducer = (token, newToken) => {
  if (newToken === null || newToken === undefined) {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    return initialState;
  }
  return newToken
};

const initialState = null


const localState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));

const AuthContext = createContext();


function AuthProvider(props) {
  const [token, setToken] = useReducer(reducer, localState || initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token));
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, setToken }}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

My whole code can be found in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-shirley-nn235). The auth.js and privateroute.js files are in the codesandbox.

Comment: Can you create a dummy email and password for testing purpose?

Comment: any email and pwd for testing purpose?

Comment: email: hehacet424@mail3tech.com, password: just-fordemo10

Comment: @krbalaji added the login for testing

Comment: It says login failed for the credentials you have provided

Comment: I just checked and it's giving me ```TypeError: Failed to fetch``` which is because maybe the login api is http and codesandbox works with https or something like that is what I read. So you have to download it and load from local server. Also the credentials are correct, I just checked now. password is just-fordemo10

Comment: Hi @UbuntuNewb. I checked in postman. got response `redirect`. Please check without stringify your body

Answer (score 0):

Here I tested your api using axios. its works charm..

```
testingMethod = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://15.206.42.0:5000/api/authenticate",
      {
        email: "hehacet424@mail3tech.com",
        password: "just-fordemo10"
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      }
    );
    console.log("response", response);
  };
```

[image: Got response]

Comment: it does log in. I want the dashboard page to be accessible only after log in.

Comment: @UbuntuNewb . use react-router-dom `browserrouter`